# Matlab plot of eigen faces in PCA algorithm for face recognition

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, pca, face-recognition

I am new to field of machine learning and matlab. I have written the code for PCA for face recognition. But when i am trying to display the eigen faces, i am getting stuck .After getting the eigen faces, how will i be able to display them . If anyone could point out my mistake i would be very grateful. I have 150 images of training set. Each image is 231*195 matrix. When i turn into column major it turns to be 45045 *1 matrix. So my mean reduced matix of all images is A= 45045*150. After taking PCA my eigen vector matrix 45045*36 (36 eigen vectors taken main features). So my eigen face matrix is 36*150.

```
    function trialtrialface

trainingdata = uigetdir('F:\Pattern recognition\face recognition\Yale','select path of training images');
testdata = uigetdir('F:\Pattern recognition\face recognition\Yale','select path of test images');

prompt = {'Enter test image name :'};
dlg_title = 'Input of PCA-Based Face Recognition System';
num_lines= 1;
def = {' '};
TestImage = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
TestImage = strcat(testdata,'\',char(TestImage),'.pgm');

%%call function
recog_img = facerecog(trainingdata,TestImage);
selected_img = strcat(trainingdata,'\',recog_img);
figure;
select_img = imread(selected_img);
imshow(select_img);
title('Recognized Image');
test_img = imread(TestImage);
figure,imshow(test_img);
title('Test Image');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
result = strcat('the recognized image is : ',recog_img);
disp(result);

function [recognized_img]=facerecog(trainingdata,testimg)

D = dir(trainingdata);  
imgcount = 0;
for i=1 : size(D,1)
    if not(strcmp(D(i).name,'.')|strcmp(D(i).name,'..')|strcmp(D(i).name,'Thumbs.db'))
        imgcount = imgcount + 1; % Number of all images in the training database
    end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  creating the image matrix X  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

X = [];
for i = 1 : imgcount
    str = strcat(trainingdata,'\',int2str(i),'.pgm');
    img = imread(str);
    [r c] = size(img);
    temp = reshape(img',r*c,1);  
%%                               
    X = [X temp];                
end

%%
%
%          m           -    (MxN)x1  Mean of the training images
%          A           -    (MxN)xP  Matrix of image vectors after each vector getting subtracted from the mean vector m
%     eigenfaces       -    (MxN)xP' P' Eigenvectors of Covariance matrix (C) of training database X
%                                    

%%%%% calculating mean image vector %%%%%

m = mean(X,2); % Computing the average face image m = (1/P)*sum(Xj's)    (j = 1 : P)
imgcount = size(X,2);

%%%%%%%%  calculating A matrix, i.e. after subtraction of all image vectors from the mean image vector %%%%%%

A = [];
for i=1 : imgcount
    temp = double(X(:,i)) - m;
    A = [A temp];
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% COV=cov(A');
L= A' * A;
[Ve,Va]=eig(L)
% [Ve,Va]=eig(COV);


 L_eig_vec = [];

DD=diag(Va);
sorted=sort(DD,'descend');
D=sorted/sum(sorted);
% AA = Va;
sumA = cumsum(D);
kk = find(sumA < 0.9)
sum1 = sumA(kk)
for ii=1:length(kk)
    L_eig_vec=[L_eig_vec Va(:,kk(ii))];
end

eigenfaces = A * L_eig_vec;   %eigenfaces 

for i=1:size(eigenfaces,2)
    img=reshape(eigenfaces(:,i),c,r);
    img=img';
    img=histeq(img,255);
    subplot(ceil(sqrt(imgcount)),ceil(sqrt(imgcount)),i)
    imshow(img)
    drawnow;
    if i==1
        title('Eigenfaces','fontsize',18)
    end
end

projectimg = [ ];  % projected image vector matrix
for i = 1 : size(A,2)
    temp = eigenfaces' * A(:,i);
    projectimg = [projectimg temp];
end

F     = projectimg;




%%
%%%%% extractiing PCA features of the test image %%%%%

test_image = imread(testimg);
test_image = test_image(:,:,1);
[r c] = size(test_image);
temp = reshape(test_image',r*c,1); % creating (MxN)x1 image vector from the 2D image
temp = double(temp)-m; % mean subtracted vector
projtestimg = eigenfaces'*temp; % projection of test image onto the facespace

%%%%% calculating & comparing the euclidian distance of all projected trained images from the projected test image %%%%%

euclide_dist = [ ];

for i=1 : size(eigenfaces,2)
    temp = (norm(projtestimg-projectimg(:,i)));
    euclide_dist = [euclide_dist temp];
end


[euclide_dist_min recognized_index] = min(euclide_dist);
recognized_img = strcat(int2str(recognized_index),'.pgm');
end



end
```

Comment: Your eigenvector marix==eigenface matrix is 45045*36. each 45045x1 is one of the eigenfaces. You just need to reshape them

Comment: Sir i have edited the code and reshaped the eigen faces. But the eigen faces that comes are eigen faces of the first 3 persons and 6 eigen faces of the 4th person ( each person have 10 samples; total i have 15 persons). So i am confused , if my algorithm is correct

Comment: the eigenfaces are for all people, they are just eigenvectors that "look like faces"

Comment: so sir, will i be able to see the eigen face projection of all images. how can i proceed?